# stanfordNPL Chinese relationship extracor

Tags: stanford-nlp, relationship-extraction

I would like to extract the Chinese relationship through the stanfordNLP, there is no example of training or have been trained in the Chinese relational model? very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example command for getting the TAC-KBP relations from Stanford CoreNLP:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref,entitymentions,kbp -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```